# Php Cache Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching

I have a problem with PHP cache. My english level is low, that's why try to understand please.

I sent a query to the database, and created a cache file. But cache file is not read and when cache file time ended, the cache file is not deleted.

How can I solve? and also, what is the difference between cache file and htaccess caching?

Comment: what method do you use for caching?

Comment: @AndreasLinden there are my codes for caching in this link -> http://pastebin.com/MCukyKpe

Answer (score 0):

Try using `is_readable($file)` before you make use of the file to determine if it's related to permissions and such

Answer (score 0):

If you want the correct answer we need to know how exactly you cached the data. There are lots of methods to cache the data like APC or MemCache or File Cache.

Ex Cache for SuperCache

https://packagist.org/packages/smart-php/super-cache

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use SuperCache\SuperCache as sCache;

//Saving cache value with a key
// sCache::cache('<key>')->set('<value>');
// $data = <your data from databse>
sCache::cache('myKey')->set($data);

//Retrieving cache value with a key
$data = sCache::cache('myKey')->get();
?>
```